# Finding the principal root of a finite summation of sines with amplitudes equal to their frequencies.

Tags: sequences-and-series, roots

I have an equation of the form
$$\sum_{k=1}^{N} a_k \sin \left( 2 \pi \, a_k \, x  \,+ \, \theta_k\right) = 0, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}, \quad a_k \in \mathbb{R}, \quad \theta_k \in [-\pi, \pi),$$
and I'm looking for the smallest magnitude value of $x$ for which the equality is satisfied. Notice that, for any particular sinusoid in the sum, its amplitude and frequency have the same value $a_k$. If it simplifies things, we can assume that $\theta_k \in [-\phi, \phi) \subset [-\pi, \pi)$---the phase angles are in some smaller range centered on zero. Is there any closed-form solution in general? The reason that I ultimately want a closed-form solution is that I wish to model the $\theta_k$ s as random, and then quantify the variance of the solution.